# How to use if statements in width condition with LESS

Tags: html, less

i need help if statements with **width** condition in less. when i add **(even)** list, its divided width in to 50%-50%, if i add **(odd)** list, in my **last** li need to 100% width.
i have also share codepen link & screenshot.
**thanks in advance**

html code is :

```html
<ul>
    <li><span> list 1</span></li>
    <li><span> list 2</span></li>
    <li><span> list 3</span></li>
    <li><span> list 4</span></li>
    <li><span> list 5</span></li>
</ul>
```

less code :

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 300px;
  li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
    span {
      display: block;
      background-color: gray;
      padding: 3px;
    }
  }
}
```

codepen link : [demo](https://codepen.io/gkldh/pen/YzXrZbz)

image link :  [image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m08GP.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
&:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd) {
  width: 100%!important;
}
```

Check the updated style

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 300px;

  li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;

    &:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd) {
      width: 100% !important;
    }

    span {
      display: block;
      background-color: gray;
      padding: 3px;
    }
  }
}
```

Check the jsfiddle demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4zms7Lgc/3/)

Comment: thanks @Akhil-Aravind  for your reply & helped and any chance in less ??

Comment: @GauravK you can use the same in less also, and there is no need for `if` condition, last odd child will always have full width. You test it by making the list `even`

Answer (score 1):

you can give `li:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd)`. This will apply if the last child is an odd number.

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  max-width:300px;
}
li {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    color:white;
    box-sizing:border-box;
       padding:5px;
    
}
span {
      display:block;
       background-color:gray;
      padding:3px;
}
li:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd) {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span> list 1</span></li>
  <li><span> list 2</span></li>
  <li><span> list 3</span></li>
  <li><span> list 4</span></li>
  <li><span> list 5</span></li>
</ul>
```